# Solving two equations in polar coordinates where one of the equations is $r = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Problem:
Find the points of intersection of the following two curves.
\begin{align*}
r &= 1 \\
r &= 2 \sin 2\theta
\end{align*}
Answer:
I did plot the curve and the two curves appeared to intersect at $8$ points. I am
not sure how to show the graph here.

Looking at the plot we see that there are $8$ points where the two curves
intersect. We also see that:

1. There are two points of intersection in each quadrant.
2. At every point of intersection, we have $r = 1$.

The above facts suggests that this system of equations will have
$8$ solutions. However, it has only $4$ solutions because some
of the points of intersection occur when $r = -1$.
Now we need to find the possible values for $\theta$.
\begin{align*}
2 \sin 2\theta &= 1 \\
\sin 2\theta &= \dfrac{1}{2} \\
\text{Let }u = 2\theta \\
\sin u &= \dfrac{1}{2} \\
\end{align*}
Now we have $u = \dfrac{\pi}{6} \pm 2\pi$ or $u = \dfrac{5\pi}{6} \pm 2\pi$.
The values for $\theta$ are $\dfrac{\pi}{12} \pm \pi$ or
$\dfrac{5\pi}{12} \pm \pi$. Hence, the four points are:
$$\left( 1, \dfrac{\pi}{12} \right),
\left( 1, \dfrac{5 \pi}{12}  \right),
\left( 1, \dfrac{13 \pi}{12}  \right),
\left( 1, \dfrac{17 \pi}{12}  \right) $$

The book's answer is:
$$\left( 1, \pm \dfrac{\pi}{12} \right),
 \left( 1, \pm \dfrac{5 \pi}{12}  \right),
 \left( 1, \pm\dfrac{13 \pi}{12}  \right),
 \left( 1, \pm\dfrac{17 \pi}{12}  \right) $$
According to the book, $\left( 1, -\dfrac{\pi}{12} \right)$ is a point
of intersection. However,
$$ r = 2 \sin ( 2 \theta )
 = 2 \sin\left( -2\left( \dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)  \right) = -1$$
Therefore it seems to me that  $\left( 1, -\dfrac{\pi}{12} \right)$ does not
satisfy both equations and it is not a point of intersection. What am I missing?

Comment: in polar coordinates, $r$ is non-negative, so $r\ne-1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So when $\theta = -\dfrac{pi}{12}$, what is $r$?

Comment: $r$ can be negative, i.e. $(-1,0)$ and $(1,\pi)$ are the same points. In this case, $(-1, -\pi/12)$ is the same point as $(1, 11\pi/12)$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In polar cordinates $(r_1,\theta_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2)$ gives the same point when
$$r_1=r_2\text{ and }\theta_1=\theta_2\mod 2\pi$$
and
$$r_1=-r_2\text{ and }\theta_1=\pi+\theta_2\mod 2\pi$$

when at least one of $r_1,r_2$ is non-zero and, $f(0,\theta_1)=f(0,\theta_2)$ for all $\theta_1,\theta_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

Since you are finding for the points which $f(1,\theta)=f(2\sin(2\theta),\theta)$ and since $2\sin(-2\theta)=-2\sin(2\theta)$, $(1,\theta)$  is a solution iff $(1,-\theta)$ is a solution.

Here $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is the function defined by $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ for all $r,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

*Verify you result by fallowing plot,*
[image]

Comment: this is a nice solution

Comment: It should be $\theta_1\equiv \theta_2+\pi$.

Comment: @AlanAbraham yes, you're correct

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates, we have to deal with the fact that points do not have a unique expression as a coordinate pair. In particular, we have that $(r,\theta)$ is the same point as
$$(r,\theta+2\pi n)~\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$(-r,\theta+(2n+1)\pi)~\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Moreover, these expressions evidently include all possible coordinate pair expressions for a single point (excluding the pole).

Using this, the points of intersection of our two curves are the solutions to
$$1=2\sin (2(\theta+2\pi n))$$
or
$$1=-2\sin (2(\theta+(2n+1)\pi))$$

The first equation gives solutions of
$$\sin (2(\theta+2\pi n))=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\implies 2(\theta+2\pi n)=\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi k,\frac{5\pi}{6}+2\pi k$$
$$\implies \theta+2\pi n=\frac{\pi}{12}+\pi k,\frac{5\pi}{12}+\pi k$$
$$\implies \theta\equiv \frac{\pi}{12},\frac{5\pi}{12},\frac{7\pi}{12},\frac{11\pi}{12}\mod 2\pi$$

The second equation gives solutions of
$$\sin (2(\theta+2\pi n))=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\implies 2(\theta+2\pi n)=-\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi k,-\frac{5\pi}{6}+2\pi k$$
$$\implies \theta+2\pi n=-\frac{\pi}{12}+\pi k,-\frac{5\pi}{12}+\pi k$$
$$\implies \theta\equiv -\frac{\pi}{12},-\frac{5\pi}{12},-\frac{7\pi}{12},-\frac{11\pi}{12}\mod 2\pi$$

So our 8 points of intersection are $\boxed{(1,\pm\frac{\pi}{12}),(1,\pm\frac{5\pi}{12}),(1,\pm\frac{7\pi}{12}),(1,\pm\frac{11\pi}{12})}$

Comment: When $\theta = -\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, I get $r = -1$ in the second equation. What am I missing?

Comment: @Bob How did you get that, when I plug in $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}$, I get $r=2\sin (-\pi)=0$?

Comment: Abrham My last question had a  mistake in it. I meant to say when $\theta = -\dfrac{\pi}{12}$, I get $r = -1$ in the second equation. What am I missing?

Comment: @Bob That was the purpose of my first paragraph. It is possible for two polar coordinates to have radius of opposite signs and still map to the same point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example, $(1,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(-1,\frac{3\pi}{2})$ both have cartesian coordinates of $(0,1)$